# How to get many object types returned in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate + JSF + Spring3

In a query, I need to get many object types returned as a result.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getReportHoursPerUser(){
   return (ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>)getHibernateTemplate().
          find(" SELECT u , SUM(r.hours) " +
               " FROM Report r, User u " +
               " WHERE r.responsible.idUser = u.idUser ");
}
```

But storing the result in an Array of Arrays of objects is not an elegant idea.. 
Moreover, I get this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

When I do this in my managed Bean :

```
reports = reportService.getReportHoursPerUser();
for (int i = 0 ; i <reports.size() ; i++ ){
      User u = (User) reports.get(i).get(0);
}
```

Is there any predefined methods to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: See more general question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828372/return-several-fields-with-jparepository

Answer (score 1):

Usual JPA return type for the query

```
find(" SELECT u , SUM(r.hours) FROM Report r, User u " +
           " WHERE r.responsible.idUser = u.idUser ")
```

is `ArrayList<Object[]>`. `Object[0]` is user and `Object[1]` must be relevant data type for hours.