# Return several fields with JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

What if I want to return several fields by `JpaRepository` class:

```
@Query("select u.age, count(u.id) from User u group by u.age")
List<Map<String, Object>> getAgeHistogram();
```

instead of one? Is t possible? According to [JPQL BNF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html) it is not possible:

```
select_expression ::=
    single_valued_path_expression |
    aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable |
    OBJECT(identification_variable) |
    constructor_expression
```

unless you use `constructor_expression` and [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (I don't test this code):

```
@Query("select new org.dao.dto.AgeHistogram(u.age, count(u.id)) from User u"
        +" group by u.age")
org.dao.dto.AgeHistogram getAgeHistogram();
```

**UPDATE** This answer show some technique: [How to get many object types returned in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546805/how-to-get-many-object-types-returned-in-hibernate) Is it possible in JPA?

Comment: There should be nothing preventing you from doing so, would render JPA queries quite useless if it wasn't supported. What is it that doesn't work, what is the result and what did you expect? You can use the constructor approach with JPA as well.